# C# regular expressions for integers

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a static method that validates if input is actually a number or not and I want to do it with a regex. I get an error "cannot convert int to string" when I try to do it, but it's my understanding that integers also can be compared using regex.

This is my static method so far.

```
public static void validatenumber(int number)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("^[0-9]+$");

        if (regex.IsMatch(number))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The input is a number");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The input is not a number");
        }
    }
```

And this is the input that I am trying to validate, which is in the Main method.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
        int number= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        validatenumber(number);
```

My variable `number` in my Main method **needs** to be an int, I cannot change that.

Comment: What is the point in checking that an `int` is a number? Of course it's a number, otherwise you would get a runtime exception.

Comment: @KobyDouek What i intend is checking that the user doesn't input letters or other symbols instead of a number..

Comment: You have an issue with `int number= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` check out my answer below.

Comment: Forget about regex - they're overkill here. `int.TryParse` is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not the `Regex` error you are getting, but the fact that you are trying to validate an `int` as a number. There is no sense in this validation, since the compiler will never allow an `int` variable to hold something else except a number.

It would make sense if yot method was receiving a `string` as a parameter:

`validatenumber(string number)`

In which case, you would not get this error, since `Regex` works with strings.

Comment: so I should not validate this with regex then?, only use it on strings?

Comment: Yes sir. `Regex` is to validate string only. There is no need to validate `int` variables as numbers - they **must** be numbers.

Comment: It looks like your input would be from a text box, if that is the case, it comes out as a string. Validate this, and parse it where necessary. @hendrix

Comment: @Koby Appreciate the help, I have only used regex on strings and suddenly thought I should validate the numbers too, pretty dumb idea I guess.

Comment: @hendrix - actually, your `Console.ReadLine()` will return a string. Your `Convert.ToInt32` will throw an exception. See my comment to your post.

Answer (score 3):

An issue with you code is found here, which leads to your regex (as you have to perform regex on a `string` not an `int`).

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
int number= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // <--- Here!
validatenumber(number);
```

> `Console.ReadLine()` will return a string. So your code will throw an error or give you an unexpected result when you try to do `Convert.ToInt32()` on it.

You will need to change your code to look like the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
    string numberString = Console.ReadLine();
    int number = ConvertAndValidateNumber(number); // we are now going to return an int

    ...
}
```

and then change the the `validatenumber` method to return the `int` type using the `int.TryParse()` method, which is much easier to read.

```
public static int ConvertAndValidateNumber(string numberString)
{
    int.TryParse(numberString, out int number);
    return number; 
}
```

If you REALLY want to use RegEx (which makes sense in some very special cases), then you can change the above method to:

```
public static int ConvertAndValidateNumberUsingRegEx(string numberString)
{
    int number;

    // 
    // put your RegEx here...
    //

    // and don't forget to assign the converted string value into the number
    number = (your converted string);

    // return it
    return number; 
}
```

You also may want to validate that your regex is valid by testing it here http://regexr.com/

Comment: My issue here is that I get an exception when the the user inputs letters, that is what i am trying to control but with no success.

Comment: @hendrix I updated my answer to be more concise with your question.